# How to stop jQuery .focus() function when you click anywhere else on the page

Tags: javascript, jquery, focus

I'm using the following JS to make sure the number keys affect a text field input, enabling the user to press up or down to change the input quantity of the text field.

Please note, swapping to a number field is not a viable option, it needs to stay a text field.

At the moment, this code works when you click the input field by using .focus(), but when you click anywhere outside the input, the page scrolls (as it should) as well as the input number changing (I need to prevent this).

I'd like to only execute this code while the input is focussed, so when clicking anywhere else in the page, the up and down arrows will simply scroll the page as usual, not affecting the text input number.

I've tried event.preventDefault() and event.stopPropagation() in every line to try and stop it, but I must be missing something. I'm not very good with JS, so it's not obvious to me and after hours of searching and reading docs, I still haven't had any luck.

Thanks in advance!

```js
jQuery(document).ready(function($) {

  var $input = $('input.qty[type="text"]');

  $input.focus(function() {
    $(document).on('keydown', function(event) {
      if (event.which == 38 || event.which == 104) {
        $input.val((parseInt($input.val()) + 1));
      } else if (event.which == 40 || event.which == 98) {
        $input.val((parseInt($input.val()) - 1));
      }
    });
  });
  
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input class="qty" type="text">
```

Comment: input.blur.... document.off...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Simply change your code to only fire the keydown event function on the input element.

Also your code has a few flaws:

1. Binding the `$(document).on(...)` event handler *inside* the `$input.focus` event causes the code to attach a new event handler *each time* you focus the input field, causing it to fire multiple times. At first it in/decreases by 1, then by 2, 3, etc.
2. You might want to check the value of the input to be a valid number first, or you will get `NaN` as value.
3. Why don't you use `type="number"` for this in the first place? Most browser include your desired functionality "for free" for this type and on top some arrows to click on.

```js
$(document).ready(function($) {

  var $input = $('input[type=text]');

  // use $input instead document here
  $input.on('keydown', function(event) {

    var val = parseInt($input.val(),10);
    if (isNaN(val)) {
      val = 0;
    }

    if (event.which == 38 || event.which == 104) {
      val++;
    } else if (event.which == 40 || event.which == 98) {
      val--;
    }

    $input.val(val);

  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input type="text" />
<div>
Input with "type='number'" does this automatically:<br>
<input type="number" />
</div>
```

Just for fun, a fancy ES6 version would look like the following:

```
$input.on('keydown', function(event) {
    let val = parseInt($input.val())||0;
    val=([38,104].includes(event.which))?++val:[40,98].includes(event.which)?--val:val;
    $input.val(val);
});
```

Comment: I'm using `type="text"` to style the field (add plus and minus buttons to the field instead of the browser number ones).

Comment: I get a parse error when minifying this `SyntaxError: Unexpected token: name (val)`. Is there some other way to check for a valid number?

Comment: Maybe your parser does not support the `let` keyword, just replace it with a normal `var`, I change the code accordingly.

Comment: Awesome, that worked :)  And forgive my ignorance, but when would it be good to use the ES6 version? I'm pretty new to JS in general, let alone ES6.

Comment: ES is short for ECMAscript which is the official name for Javascript standardized by Ecma International. ES6 (or ES 2015) is just a version number and should be supported by most of the modern browsers nowadays. `let` is part of ES6, `Array.prototype.includes` part of ES7 (ES2016). You can look up the support here: http://kangax.github.io/compat-table/es6/ Most of ES6 features should be pretty safe to use nowadays. I would not use the below snippet at this point.

Comment: Well thanks for your comprehensive help. I'll do some more research on compatibility.

Answer (score 3):

Do it like this:

```js
jQuery(document).ready(function ($) {
    var $input = $('input.qty[type="text"]');
    // $input.focus(function() { 
        $input.on('keydown', function (event) {
            if (event.which == 38 || event.which == 104) {
                $input.val((parseInt($input.val()) + 1));
            } else if (event.which == 40 || event.which == 98) {
                $input.val((parseInt($input.val()) - 1));
            }
        }); 
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input type="text" class = "qty">
```

Just added a `if($input.is(":focus"))` check to check if your input has focus.

**--EDIT--**

As pointed out, the event `keydown` doesn't need to be attached to the whole document. Attaching it to just the input will be better and will also solve the focus problem. Updated the snippet.

Comment: Imo overkill to have the event target be the entire document.